# Discovery Registration tool - Update issue

Tags: web8, discovery-service

To register content delivery capabilities, I tried running the "discovery registration tool" in update mode as per [doc](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-12D1D919-2D08-40C3-91A0-B6C0A643C29F), while doing so, encountered below error:

```
    2016-03-22 16:46:54,775 INFO  UpdateCommand - Updating capability:         DefaultContentService
    Exception in thread "main"         com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientRuntimeException: Unable to make         POST request to OData service for "http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc" URL and service query "/ContentServiceCapabilities"
    at com.sdl.odata.client.DefaultODataClient.formFailedRequestException(DefaultODataClient.java:234)
    at com.sdl.odata.client.DefaultODataClient.updateEntity(DefaultODataClient.java:194)
    at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.SecuredODataClient.updateEntity(SecuredODataClient.java:72)
    at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.command.UpdateCommand.updateCapability(UpdateCommand.java:96)
    at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.command.UpdateCommand.performCommand(UpdateCommand.java:48)
    at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.RegistrationTool.performCommand(RegistrationTool.java:60)
    at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.Main.main(Main.java:36)
    Caused by: com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientException: Path 'http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/ContentServiceCapabilities('DefaultContentService')' is not allowed

    at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.sendRequest(BasicEndpointCaller.java:142)
    at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.doPutEntity(BasicEndpointCaller.java:176)
    at com.sdl.odata.client.DefaultODataClient.updateEntity(DefaultODataClient.java:191)
    ... 5 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/ContentServiceCapabilities('DefaultContentService')
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.sendRequest(BasicEndpointCaller.java:123)
    ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/ContentServiceCapabilities('DefaultContentSerice')
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.sendRequest(BasicEndpointCaller.java:121)
    ... 7 more
```

How to resolve this issue? Appreciate your inputs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have noted that in my cd_ambient_conf.xml of discovery service, OAuthEnabled was set to false but Rules Enabled was set to "true". Making both of them to true or false (disbaling oAuth as per [doc](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-80AD06B5-DB74-4AE8-9934-4BA8BC1C6D51)) resolved the issue.